# Xbox 360 E71 error

Tags: xbox-360

My xbox 360 cannot boot up, it just shows the logo briefly and then suddenly shows the red dot on the power button (center red dot) and an error message (E71):

`System Error. Contact Xbox Customer Support.`

The brief background of my problem is that I took the console to a local guy purporting to be good at updating jtag/rgh console dashboards. It has not worked since.

Comment: Could you put what the E71 error message is?

Comment: it says: System Error. Contact Xbox Customer Support. then at the bottom shows E71

Comment: Are you saying you have a modded xbox 360?

Comment: [Xbox Support](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/errors/error-code-e71) says to try disconnecting the consoles hard drive.  If the problem continues happening with the hard drive removed, then your Xbox needs to be repaired.

Comment: I'm kind of a noob to the terminology so you tell me based on this; I can download games via pc and burn onto disks or i can install them to my console via usb. I use xex menu 1.2. though i've been banned on xbox live.

Comment: I tried the xbox live method and it still offered no help. i also tried holding the sync button before and during the booting process (came across it as a possible solution) but it also failed.

Answer (score 1):

Checking on the Official Xbox support site, your hard drive may be broken.

https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/errors/error-code-e71

Try removing the hard drive and then starting your Xbox 360 again to see if it fixes it.

If removing the drive does not fix it, there is a different hardware error and you'll have to send it in for repair to Microsoft. Note that if your Xbox is modded, there's a chance Microsoft won't agree to repair it depending on the mods installed.

Comment: I'll try that out soon as i get home.